# How do I correctly pad negative binary numbers?

Tags: c#, binary

It works perfectly with positive numbers and I know I could just manually truncate the first two group of 1s to fix the issue but would there be a more optimal way of doing it?
The example code outputs in 32 bits instead of the specified 24 bits:

```
var s = Convert.ToString(-3, 2).PadLeft(24, '0');
Console.WriteLine(s);
//Expected: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101
//Actual: 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101
```

Comment: `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1101` is 16777213, which is not -3.

Comment: @GSerg The number of leading 1s doesn't matter, they just fill the bits not being used. If you're writing -3 in 24 bits, you wouldn't add all of the 1s that you see in the programmer's calculator. You would need just enough to fill the remaining bits.

Comment: Do you want your resulting string to have _exactly_ 24 characters?

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, it needs to fit the branch instruction for ARM which takes 24 bits.

Comment: uint opcode = (uint)offset & 0xffffff;

Comment: @HansPassant I get a syntax error when I tried 'uint opcode = (unit)s & 0xffffff;'

Comment: int offset = -3;

Comment: @HansPassant I think the OP probably wants a string here...

Comment: @HansPassant Upvoted your comment since it's the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PadLeft` applies a *minimum* length to a string, but you want your string to have a length of *exactly* 24 characters.

So in addition to `PadLeft`, you'd also need to use `Substring` to truncate your string when it's more than 24 characters:

```
string s = Convert.ToString(-3, 2);
// assuming the int is always representable by 24 bits two's complement
if (s.Length < 24) { // alternatively, check integer is positive
    s = s.PadLeft(24, '0');
} else if (s.Length > 24) { // alternatively, check integer is negative
    s = s.Substring(8);
}
```

As Hans Passant said in the comments, you can also use a bit mask to clear the most significant 8 bits of the number you are converting. This way, you don't need the if statements.

```
Convert.ToString(-3 & 0xffffff, 2).PadLeft(24, '0');
```

Comment: The first if statement should use '==' instead of '<' since the length would always be 24 if it's positive but other than that, it's a great solution.

Comment: @CLUTCHER If the length is equal 24, you don't need to do anything to do the string, right? Also, I think Hans Passant's solution in the comments is better.

Comment: If it's 24, do the normal procedure.

Comment: @CLUTCHER Actually do you know what [`PadLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8) does? It only does something if the string's length is less than the first argument.

Comment: Oh, I get it. You coded yours differently than mines. I had mine all in one line.